# Remove top level UL

Tags: jquery

```
<li> </li>   
<li class="wordwrap"></li>
```

i want to remove `li` on top level .ie `li` without a class which resides just on top of `li` with class .i don't want to remove any other `li` ? How can we do this with Jquery

Comment: What do you mean by *top level*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove the *previous sibling* `li` element, if it has no class:

```
$('li[class]').prev('li:not([class])').remove();
```

This first selects all list elements with a class. Then selects all the previous sibling list elements that have no class and removes them.

Reference: [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju5gc/) with this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="a">I will stay.</li>
    <li>I will stay although I have no class</li>
    <li>I will go away.</li>
    <li class="a">I will stay.</li>
    <li>I will go away.</li>
    <li class="a">I will stay.</li>
</ul>
```

At least this is how *I* understood it based on your description. But it is a little vague, so if it is not what you want, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wordwrap").prev().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

If your `<li class="i"></li>` is the only element with a className of `i`, then you simply do:

`$(".li").prev().remove()`

However if there are many list elements with a className of `i` then you need to match that particular one in your tree:

```
<ul id="cont">
    <li></li>
    <li class="li"></li> <!-- to reference this use $("#cont .li").get(0) -->
    <li class="li"></li> <!-- to reference this use $("#cont .li").get(1) -->
</ul>
```

Comment: @George, that's why you got a documented link, you'll see lots of sample codes there.

Answer (score 0):

if your empty list item is always the first child you could do this:

```
$(".wordwrap").parent().find("li").first().remove();
```